# Obj-C Asynchronous Basics - what to do in this simple situation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

In the function below, 'doStuff' must make a call (or even several) to foo. However, doStuff should only ever be called if it is not currently being run.

```
- (void)foo
{             
    [self doStuff];
}
```

How would one go about this in objective-c?

Comment: what do you mean 'if it is not currently being run'? and why is the question tagged asynchronous basics?

Comment: You can create a BOOL variable `BOOL doingStuff` and cll doStuff only if it's not running.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin forgive me if I'm wrong, but I assumed this was an asynchronous problem. I'm new to it, so could be completely wrong - feel free to rename the question. 'Not currently being run' means that if foo is called from doStuff, then foo should not call doStuff which would create a recursive loop.

Comment: @Jordan check my answer. Though its not thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely unsure as to why this has been dubbed 'asynchronous basics'. I am assuming that `doStuff` executes asynchronously, and this is why you need to worry about calling it twice.

The simplest way of doing this, unaware of the asynchronous implementation of the method, would be to creat e property like so:

```
/** Tracks whether stuff is being done. */
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isDoingStuff) BOOL doingStuff;
```

Then in the `foo` method:

```
/**
 * Starts the doing of required stuff.
 */
- (void)foo
{
    if (!self.isDoingStuff)
    {
        [self doStuff]
    }
}
```

In `doStuff`:

```
/**
 * Does the actual stuff.
 */
- (void)doStuff
{
    self.doingStuff = YES;

    // does all of the stuff

    self.doingStuff = NO;
}
```

Comment: Hah! I was thinking much too hard about that. Thanks

Comment: That happens all of the time to me. You're welcome man. Could you accept the answer though?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
-(void)foo
{
    static dispatch_once_t mut;
    dispatch_once(&mut, ^{
        [self doStuff];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
BOOL inFoo;

- (void)foo
{
    inFoo = YES;
    [self doStuff];
    inFoo = NO;
}

-(void)doStuff
{
    if(inFoo == NO)
        [self doStuff];
    else
        // Do Other stuff
}
```